# Object destructing of many elements

Tags: javascript

I want to use object destructuring of an object with many keys with almost the same name.
Is there a way to dynamically extract them if I know that there are a finite number of keys?

```
const {status, name1, name2, name50 } = req.body;
console.log(name12) // > john
```

I hope I´m explaining myself correctly. thank you.

Comment: Not elegantly. Use an object or array instead for the `name`s, rather than having so many separate but related properties (that way, you don't create so many standalone variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using the rest operator on the remaining props after you pluck out the `status` may be what you're going for. In the following snippet, we destructure out the `status` and put the rest of the props in a `names` object.

```js
const body = {
  status: 200,
  name1: "John",
  name2: "Joe",
  name3: "Bob"
}

const { status, ...names } = body;

console.log(names);
```